# Explode nested JSON file with two lists at different levels

Tags: python, json, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a json file laid out as below.

```json
{
  "$schema": "schema",
  "records": [
    {
      "mode": "1",      
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "id",
          "value": "111"
        },
        {
          "name": "name_1a",
          "value": "value_1a"
        },
        {
          "name": "name_1b",
          "value": "value_1b"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "mode": "2",
      "fields": [
        {
          "name": "id",
          "value": "222"
        },
        {
          "name": "name_2a",
          "value": "value_2a"
        },
        {
          "name": "name_2b",
          "value": "value_2b"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "format": "json"
}
```

I am trying to read this into a pyspark dataframe to achieve the below:

| id | name | value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 111 | mode | 1 |
| 111 | name_1a | value_1a |
| 111 | name_1b | value_1b |
| 222 | mode | 2 |
| 222 | name_2a | value_2a |
| 222 | name_2b | value_2b |

I have been able to explode the individual elements out by selecting the appropriate keys, e.g.:

```
data_fields= data_fields.select('records.mode', 'records.fields')
data_fields = data_fields.select(explode("mode"))
```

In the case of the fields I explode twice to get down to the lower level name value pairs. To extract the ids `("111,222")` I select that element from the list before I explode the fields a second time using:

```
data_fields = data_fields.withColumn('id', col('fields')[0].value)
```

But this leads to the problem. I am unsure as to how to reliably attach the "mode" record into the same format as the fields record.

How can I go about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After inlining the array of structs you could do something like this with some transformations using `when` expressions:

```
from pyspark.sql import functions as F, Window

result = (data_fields.selectExpr("inline(records)")
         .selectExpr("mode", "inline(fields)")
         .withColumn("id", F.max(F.when(F.col("name") == "id", F.col("value"))).over(Window.partitionBy("mode")))
         .withColumn("value", F.when(F.col("name") == "id", F.col("mode")).otherwise(F.col("value")))
         .withColumn("name", F.when(F.col("name") == "id", "mode").otherwise(F.col("name")))
         .drop("mode")
         )

result.show()
#+-------+--------+---+
#|   name|   value| id|
#+-------+--------+---+
#|   mode|       1|111|
#|name_1a|value_1a|111|
#|name_1b|value_1b|111|
#|   mode|       2|222|
#|name_2a|value_2a|222|
#|name_2b|value_2b|222|
#+-------+--------+---+
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks. It did add a random 'status' column from somewhere which I am investigating but this can simply be dropped to get the desired outcome.